# Windows modules installer worker 100% cpu on windows server?

Tags: windows-server

The process Windows Modules Installer Worker is running at 100% cpu usage on Windows Server 2019.

I can see that the process [enables windows templates](https://www.howtogeek.com/316122/what-is-windows-modules-installer-worker-and-why-is-it-running-on-my-pc/).

I would like to prevent this process from ever running (automatically, anyway). What is the best way to prevent it ever starting?

Answer (score 0):

This process enables Windows updates. If you disable it, you will need to regularly
and manually check for updates yourself.
Before going this way, here is some advice:

- Many reports indicate that by letting it run its course, it will eventually calm
  down to a much more moderate use of the CPU
- Killing in Task Manager the `TiWorker.exe` process may stop it temporarily,
  but it could return later
- Run the Windows Update Troubleshooter via
  *Settings > Updates & Security > Troubleshoot > Windows Update*
- Run the
  [System File Checker](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html)
  and the
  [DISM Tool](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7808-use-dism-repair-windows-10-image.html)
  to replace corrupted system files and fix a corrupted system image
- The last resort :
  [Disable automatic Windows Update](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/8013-enable-disable-windows-update-automatic-updates-windows-10-a.html).